# Apache Spark with elasticsearch V5.X

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I am a novice in Java and  I am looking for some examples of connector between elasticsearch V5.X and Spark in order to see some use cases.

At the moment here is my code :

```
package Spark;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import scala.collection.immutable.Map;
import twitter4j.Status;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;                              
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark; 

public class EsSpark {



    public EsSpark(){

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp1").setMaster("localhost");
        conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);  
        Map<String, ?> numbers = (Map<String, ?>) ImmutableMap.of("one", 1, "two", 2);                   
        Map<String, ?> airports = (Map<String, ?>) ImmutableMap.of("OTP", "Otopeni", "SFO", "San Fran");

        JavaRDD<Map<String, ?>> javaRDD = jsc.parallelize(ImmutableList.of(numbers, airports));


        JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "spark/docs");    
        }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except if you are working with a local instance of Elasticsearch, there are some important settings to be provided, notably `es.nodes`.

You can do it using

`conf.set("es.nodes", "eshost:9200");`

You can even specify multiple instances, prefer master nodes, but not all nodes are required.

Please refer to [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html).

People at discussion forum at [elastic](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/elasticsearch-and-hadoop) often publish some code you can use as example.

Ensure to provide several documents as the `EsSpark` or `EsSparkStreaming` objects. Do not send 1 document each time, prefer multiple documents.

`EsSpark` or `EsSparkStreaming` connect to the nodes you provide, they check for the cluster topology (number of nodes, types of nodes) and they will send data directly to data nodes and to the correct shard (avoiding hops).
It is possible to prevent to push data directly to the data nodes (using the settings specified in this [section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_network)), but you will introduce bottlenecks.

Comment: @lucabellucini  Thanks , how I can add this setting  es.nodes and I am using Elasticsearch in Rest how I can :"Ensure that the EsSpark and EsSparkStreaming objects are discovering the cluster at each reconnect"